# Attach .mdf file to SQL Server 2008, date format changed in datatables

Tags: sql-server

I attached a `.mdf` file to a SQL Server 2008 instance. It attached fine, but the date format has been changed from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "yyyy/mm/dd" in all the tables in that database.

I tried

```
set dateformat dmy
```

but that does not help.

Please help

But if I open the same file in SQL Server 2005, it shows "dd/mm/yyyy".

If I attach that file in SQL Server 2008, it shows "yyyy/mm/dd"

I insert the date with this code

```
 cmdInsertP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SysDate",  DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which settings provide SQL Server default datetime format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011693/which-settings-provide-sql-server-default-datetime-format)

Comment: What is the **datatype** of your column? A `DATETIME` column **does NOT have any format** - it's a 8-byte binary value. The display is handled **exclusively** by the settings in Management Studio or your own code.

Comment: datatype is DATETIME