# Getting an error while inserting data using stored procedure in mvc entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting an error

> converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Where I did mistake?

```
 var exec = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_InsertTicketChat @TicketId, 
        @FullName, @Description, 
                   @LastCorrespondanceBy,@LastCorrespondanceOn",
                new SqlParameter("@TicketId", TicketId),
                new SqlParameter("@FullName", FullName),
                new SqlParameter("@Description", Description),
                new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceBy", FullName),
                new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceOn", 
                     DateTime.Now.ToString())
                );
```

This is my stored procedure through which I want to insert data. What can I do ?

```
 INSERT INTO tblTicketChat 
 (
 TicketId,
 FullName,
 [Description],
 LastCorrespondanceOn,
 LastCorrespondanceBy

  )
     VALUES
   (
 @TicketId,
 @FullName,
 @Description,
 GETDATE(),
 @LastCorrespondanceBy)
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to show the code of the stored procedure

Comment: I edit it kindly check.

Comment: Why are you calling  `GETDATE(),` AND passing in a date?

Comment: Because if I not pass date it through as error.

Comment: Don't pass it as a parameter then. GETDATE is supplying the value

Comment: Not working same error.

Comment: can you provide full store procedure including the type like `@LastCorrespondanceOn` is `varchar` or `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the root cause of the issue you were facing.

Ideally, `DateTime.Now.ToString()` should have got converted to SQL Server Datetime data type when being assigned to the `@LastCorrespondanceOn` parameter of your stored procedure but it threw an exception.

The reason is date time format settings of your operating system.

The thing is when you perform `DateTime.Now.ToString()` in your C# language based client code it takes the default settings of date time format from your operating system. Look at the date time format currently set on my windows 10 box:

[image]

Due to this setting the code `DateTime.Now.ToString()` emits `27-07-2017 18:07:37`. The output you're seeing is `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Now this `dd-MM-yyyy` date format is not recognizable by SQL Server as per your default language settings.

SQL Server can recognize two date time formats when sent as string from client side

1. International date format `yyyy-MM-dd` also known as ISO 8601 .
2. Date format controlled by user login's dateformat setting. You can run `dbcc useroptions` command to see the value of setting. For me it is set to `mdy`

Due to this mismatch in the date time format being sent by your C# code (because of your operating system) and what SQL server can parse, you faced the issue.

When you did the conversion explicitly by `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` you simply aligned it ISO 8601 international date time format supported by SQL Server so it started to work.

The default date time format (ISO 8601) of SQL Server is a configuration of the collation you are using currently which you can check in your SQL Server instance properties as shown below:

[image]

It is strongly recommended that you should always use SQL's date time format when passing it in string format as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/331420/465053) thread.

So you can solve your problem in three ways:

1. Change the default date format of your OS to align it to SQL Server (Not recommended). It will never be feasible on all client computers where your application runs.
2. Use custom date format while calling `ToString` method as you have done to align it to one of the formats supported by SQL Server. Best format is ISO 8601 format which you've used.
3. Don't convert it to string. Just pass the date time value as is.

   ```
   var exec = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_InsertTicketChat @TicketId, 
   @FullName, @Description, 
              @LastCorrespondanceBy,@LastCorrespondanceOn",
           new SqlParameter("@TicketId", TicketId),
           new SqlParameter("@FullName", FullName),
           new SqlParameter("@Description", Description),
           new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceBy", FullName),
           new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceOn", 
                DateTime.Now) //Don't call .ToString here
           );
   ```

   Approach # 3 is the best deal. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27012211/465053) as to why you shouldn't use strings but the date time data type while dealing with  SQL Server datetime columns.

Comment: @razasarwar it can't be the same error - have you edited BOTH c# and SP as per the above code

Comment: thanks guys !! I fixed this issue by formatting date as dd-MM-yyyy in my storedprocedure.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issues by using MSSQL string formatted (dd-MM-yyyy) in my storedprocedure

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by doing some changes.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string strDateTime = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


            var exec = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_InsertTicketChat @TicketId, @FullName, @Description, @LastCorrespondanceOn, @LastCorrespondanceBy",
                new SqlParameter("@TicketId", TicketId),
                new SqlParameter("@FullName", FullName),
                new SqlParameter("@Description", Description),
                new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceBy", "raza"),
                new SqlParameter("@LastCorrespondanceOn", strDateTime)
                );
```

Comment: why are you storing `LastCorrespondanceOn` as a string in the db!?

Comment: @Alex I believe `@LastCorrespondanceOn` will still get saved as `datetime`. Even a string in appropriate date time format gets converted to datetime

Comment: @razasarwar I got the root cause of your problem. Please see my updated answer.