# How do I modify the datetime format in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: datetime, ssms

I'm testing a query that I think is handling datetime values in a way that may not work for customers who aren't using a specific datetime format.

Here's the code:
`WHERE order_instant >= CONCAT(YEAR(cast(getdate() as date)) ,'-01-01')`

I suspect this code would break if a customer had datetimes formatted as anything other than year - month - day, but I'm having trouble testing that hunch.

The column datatype is datetime.

I'm looking for something analogous to the NLS settings in Oracle SQL Developer, which allows me to do things like display dates as YYYY-MON-DD or MM-DD-YY.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011693/which-settings-provide-sql-server-default-datetime-format#27012211

Which essentially goes into why that kind of query may be bad. If the default format changes, that statement doesn't take that into account. Using Convert or Format_Date might be better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/write-international-transact-sql-statements?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Never mind--got it. If the datetime column contains a 4-digit value for one of the parts, that is automatically interpreted as the year. So 2018-01-01 will always be interpreted "correctly." If I switch to something like 2018-12-31, I start to get datetime conversion errors in other languages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017