# How to fix date formats in Delphi 10.4 CE

Tags: delphi

I'm facing date format problems in Delphi 10.4 CE.

If the `date` fields are created in SQL server with `DateTime` format, and a date field is incremented in the application with a specific number of days using the `System.DateUtils.IncDay()` function while the source date is `01/10/2022`, I get the result as `01/09/1900` in the `DBEdit` component and in `DBGrid` when incremented by 10 days.

However, if I recreate date fields with formatting as `Date` fields (and not `DateTime`), the increment function shows errors like:

> '' is not a valid date and time

Moreover, if I skip the increment function and add a record to the SQL table, the dates are shown in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, but after adding records once, if I close the session and restart the application, all dates show up in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Following is the source code to calculate the incremented date:

```pascal
tblLeaveAzr.FieldByName('leaveend').AsDateTime := IncDay(tblLeaveAzr.FieldByName('leavestart').AsDateTime,tblLeaveAzr.FieldByName('leavedays').AsInteger);
```

I have been working in Delphi 6, 7 and 2009 for more than 20 years, but never faced such a problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and include actual code that you use to modify the dates. Also include any locale information that applies to your code.

Comment: Are you using SQL parameters?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, I have edited the query and included the source code.

Comment: @Delphi Coder, No I'm not using any SQL parameter, it's simply calculated with Delphi coding directly referring to the SQL ADOtable fields.

Comment: I have currently solved the problem by using the component values for calculation rather than the table field values to add days to the leave start date to get the leave end date. What I feel is that the values entered by the user in the UI are still not written to the table from the DBEdit components therefore the result was confusing. However, I thank Tom Brunberg and Delphi Coder for showing their interest.

Comment: Dates are stored internally by SQL Server in its own format, not as a string, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011693 which-settings-provide-sql-server-default-datetime-format). When you query using SSMS it will use ISO 8601 format (by default, I'm not sure if that can be changed).
In general DO NOT pass dates as strings, use parameterised queries. The driver will take care of everything from there.